# R use regex to select all fields in data.frame

Tags: regex, r, quotes, write.table

I need to save a data.table with write.table in R. The problem is that some values (downloaded from the internet) have a single ". I can't choose a different quote character, as I can in read.table (what's gross, I think). So I've read about using gsub() to select all fields, and replace them adding a different quotation mark, and finally using quote=F in write.table (with sep="\t").

Let's say that's my table:

```
field1  field2  field3
valueA  valueB  valueC
valueD  valueE  valueF
valueG  value\"H    valueI
```

Because of the \" in value\"H I have problems with quotation, and need a different quotation mark, a character that I'm sure won't appear anywhere else in the file, say, a chinese character. So, I want to produce this with gsub:

```
乃field1乃    乃field2乃    乃field3乃
乃valueA乃    乃valueB乃    乃valueC乃
乃valueD乃    乃valueE乃    乃valueF乃
乃valueG乃    乃value\"H乃  乃valueI乃
```

But how do I select all fields with gsub()? I can't find the correct regex for that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `lapply` if that is what you meant. i.e. `lapply(yourdf, function(x) gsub(pat, replacement, x))`

Comment: ??? No, I just need to know which regex will select all the values between my separator (\t), i.e. what would be my pat and replacement in your lapply?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear for me. Thanks. pat will be the quote that you need to match and replacement the one that will be replaced.  Without some examples, it is not easy

Comment: My english is that bad? I just need to select ALL the fields in the table, since I can't choose the quote character (and it can't be ")

Comment: I didn't say anything about your english.  I just said that I didn't understand it.

Comment: Could you provide some example data?

Comment: Looks like you need paste. i.e. `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) paste0('乃', x, '乃'))`

Comment: @LegalizeIt  Why did you delete your answer?  The OP asked about using `regex`

Comment: @akrun I think yours is better here :)

Comment: Actually the regex is not necessary. I just thought it would be. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `paste`

```
 df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) paste0('乃', x, '乃'))
 df1
 #   field1      field2     field3
 #1 乃valueA乃  乃valueB乃 乃valueC乃
 #2 乃valueD乃  乃valueE乃 乃valueF乃
 #3 乃valueG乃 乃value"H乃 乃valueI乃
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(field1 = c("valueA", "valueD", "valueG"), 
 field2 = c("valueB", 
 "valueE", "value\"H"), field3 = c("valueC", "valueF", "valueI"
 )), .Names = c("field1", "field2", "field3"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness (akrun's version via `paste` is more appropriate here), this is one using `gsub`:

```
df <- read.table(text='field1 field2 field3
                       valueA valueB valueC
                       valueD valueE valueF
                       valueG value\"H valueI')

as.data.frame( lapply(df, function(x) gsub("(.*)","乃\\1乃",x)) )

#          V1          V2        V3
# 1 乃field1乃  乃field2乃 乃field3乃
# 2 乃valueA乃  乃valueB乃 乃valueC乃
# 3 乃valueD乃  乃valueE乃 乃valueF乃
# 4 乃valueG乃 乃value"H乃 乃valueI乃
```